# Duda en php al generar archivos txt

Tags: php

Estoy intentando generar un archivo .txt sencillo con php y no me lo permite. este es mi formulario:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Guardar archivos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="guardar.php" method="POST" name="frm">
        <input type="text" name="nombre"><br><br>
        <textarea name="comentario"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar datos">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

y este es mi generador de archivos:

```
<?php 


$fi = fopen("archivo.txt", "a") or die ("Problemas al crear archivo");

$nom = $_REQUEST['nombre'];
$com = $_REQUEST['comentario'];

fwrite($fi, "Datos: ");
fwrite($fi, "\n");
fwrite($fi,$nom);
fwrite($fi, "\n");
fwrite($fi,$com);
fwrite($fi, "\n");
fwrite($fi, "----------------------------------------------------- \n \n");
fclose($fi);
echo "Archivo guardado";
?>
```

Lo que sucede es que siempre me genera el mensaje que va en caso del or die.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: este es el formulario:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Guardar archivos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="guardar.php" method="POST" name="frm">
        <input type="text" name="nombre"><br><br>
        <textarea name="comentario"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar datos">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Estás ejecutando tu script en un entorno unix/linux? windows?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El nombre del archivo esta mal definido.

Como indica en la [documentación de fopen](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php) la ruta del archivo debe ser completa no solo el nombre del archivo, al no encontrar la ruta se va al `or die`.

Lo correcto deberia ser asi:

```
fopen("c:\\archivo.txt", "a") or die
```

Comment: Estás dando por hecho que ejecuta el script en un entorno windows, cuando en realidad no se indica. La ruta "archivo.txt" podría considerarse como un fichero en el directorio raíz del script ejecutado, en caso de linux, podría ser un problema de permisos. En qué parte de la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php) se afirma que no puede ser una ruta relativa y solo son válidas las rutas absolutas?

Comment: tome como ejemplo la documentación no lo estoy afirmado simplemente tu lo dices estoy asumiendo un entorno Windows y dando un ejemplo. ya sea linux de cualquier forma deberia poner la ruta. `/home/archivo.txt` por ejemplo, si es de una url debe poner la ruta `http://145.451.4.26/archivo.txt`. y deje la documentación para que la pueda revisar.

Comment: Y te digo que "archivo.txt" es una ruta.

Comment: Y no digo lo contrario. En todo caso me apresure a responder pero lo que veo en la documentación me sugiere que se debe poner la ruta completa. o en todo caso `@fopen('archivo.txt')` como uno de los ejemplos lo muestra.

Comment: Entiendo estoy en un entorno linux (Ubuntu 16.04 lts) y no había tenido en cuenta la parte de los permisos. Muchísimas gracias!